# How to access javascript variable in Rails code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I make this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var id = 10;

  <% @comment = Comment.find(id) %>
</script>
```

`id` is a javascript var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a javascript variable is set on the client side.
So you can't access that value on the server side in just one request.
The solution is to make another request (ajax) and pass the variable.